# get user's create events from facebook by user id using graph api

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-access-token

I've developed an mvc 5 based application. What i actually need if i am a normal facebook user and i created some events on my facebook after i login on my developed website then i want that events to display on my website.
I set the user_events permission and i get my access_token as my code is below.

```
var client = new Facebook.FacebookClient(accessToken);
dynamic facebookEvents = client.Get("/v2.8/me/events/created");
```

but this is only returns owners created events if my appid and my app_secret then it's returning only my created events not returning other users events who's login with facebook on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the events of other users, you have to authorize them with `user_events` too, and use THEIR user access token with that API call.

Make sure you know "Login Review" too, most permissions don´t just work for every user without approval: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: yes i did the same things authorize with user_events and also user there access_token but i can't get user events. i only get when my appKey and apiSecret and it's only return my creted events.

Comment: _“yes i did the same things authorize with user_events”_ – so are you testing this with another user that has a role in the app? Because before you can ask normal users for the permission, you of course need to get it reviewed by Facebook.

Comment: Ok so it's need a Login review. Thanks for your answer.